# th:field attribute has a red underline in fragment thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have this fragment, it opens a modal when a button is clicked and inside that model is a form with a text field for token and submit button.

However the th:field attribute token appears to have the red squiggle underneath so I'm not sure I am doing wrong. I think it is something to do with using fragments but I am not sure how to fix this. And because of this, when invalid input/blank field is entered in the token field then no errors are displayed in the errors div where field.errors('token') is used.

```
<div th:fragment="joinTeamByToken(joinTeamForm, tokenInvalid)">

    <form id="forgot-password-form" th:action="@{my-teams}" method="post" th:object="${joinTeamForm}">


    <div class="submit-button">
        <button id="joinTeamByTokenModalBtn" type="button" class="registerLoginButton">Join Team by Token</button>
    </div>


    <div id="joinTeamModal" class="modal" th:style="${tokenInvalid != null ? 'display:block' : 'display:none'}">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <h4 class="reset-password-info"> Join Team By Token </h4>

            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="token" placeholder="" th:field="*{token}" th:value="${token}"
                       data-cy="token" autofocus>
                <label for="token"> Token: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            </div>

            <div th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('token')}" th:text="${err}" class="error-message"></div>


            <div class="submit-button">
                <button id="joinTeam" type="submit" class="registerLoginButton">Join Team</button>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

the @PostMapping to post upon submit

```
 @PostMapping("/my-teams")
    public String joinTeamsForm(
            @RequestParam("token") String token,
            @Validated JoinTeamForm joinTeamForm,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, HttpServletRequest request,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {

        model.addAttribute("token", token);
        model.addAttribute("httpServletRequest", request);

        User user = userService.getCurrentUser().get();
        Optional<Team> team = teamService.findByToken(token);


        if(team.isEmpty()) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("tokenInvalid", "Token is null");
        }

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("tokenInvalid", "Token is null");
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            return "redirect:/my-teams?page=1";
        }

        if(team.isPresent()) {
            Team teamToJoin =  team.get();
            user.joinTeam(teamToJoin);
            userService.updateOrAddUser(user);
        }
        
        return "redirect:/my-teams?page=1";
    }
```

JoinTeamForm

```
public class JoinTeamForm {

    @NotBlank(message = "Field cannot be blank")
    private String token;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

Why did you set multiple html attributes with thymeleaf and with standard html attributes ? It should work well using the `th:field` thymeleaf tag, I bet that's why your code editor underline that with red, because `th:id` and `th:value` are redundant :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" 
       th:field="*{token}" data-cy="token" autofocus/>
```

Comment: It still appears red and doesn't work if I do that

Comment: Which editor are you using ?

Comment: do you have added the doctype inside the file ?

Comment: do you have added the thymeleaf XML namespace inside your fragment file ? `<html lang="fr" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">`